# How to clear Python cache while running a daemon since old version of the file is being executed?

Tags: python, supervisord

I really don't know how to explain this better, but here's what I am doing: git pull to fetch the new file
stopped, and started supervisord (incase that effects this process)
then when I run the code, the old version of the file is still being executed.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @pyjavo unfortunately no, been 5 years, and haven't used python since ......